# Storage of pH test equipment

Tags: ph

I am looking to buy a pH meter like the one below, to more accurately balance acidity when making cider from fresh apples.

More expensive testers seem to require the probes are stored in a solution to prevent them being damaged.

Do these less expensive testers need to be cleaned or stored in any kind of solution to prevent long term damage?

[image: Handheld pH tester]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, no matter what kind of pH tester you get, you need to store it with the probe in storage solution.  You'll also need both the 4 and 7 calibration solutions.  Some people say you can use the 4 for storage, but experts I've talked to recommend using the storage solution instead.  even with that, you may be looking at replacing the probe every few years.  If you don't need a very exact reading, which you may not for cider, pH papers may be a better, less expensive solution.

Comment: Thanks. Papers are not very helpful in my experience. With the model type I pictured I'm unsure how you would store the inbuilt probe in solution, unless the cap is somehow liquid tight.

Comment: Have you tried ColorpHast papers?  They're plastic strips and pretty much the only ones that are worthwhile.  As to storage, you could put storage solution in a container, cut a hole in the lid, and put the probe through the hole into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

All pH meters should be stored in storage solution to keep the electrode and reference junction damp.

---

I'm not sure how much you are looking to spend, but I use this Extech model that sells for under $100 on Amazon: [Extech PH100](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00023RYQ8)

It has a cap with a little sponge in it to hold the storage solution, which makes storage super simple.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up buying one of these models on your recommendation.